# Angular 2 - how to select value from dropdown list and submit the value? (not showing selected value)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, data-binding, dropdown

I want to select a value from a dropdown list and submit the selected value in mlab database.

Currently, I'm able to display all the data in the dropdown but I'm not able to select a value it just shows the "Select..." text on the button even after I select the value from the list. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything (ngModel or formControlName) - I would like to select the value from the list and then save it to the db.

Also, I have connected everything to the db as I'm able to save other input fields except this dropdown one.

**Code:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Select...
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let user of users" attr.data-value={{user._id}} id="person">{{ user.username }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would us a select for this and do an ngFor for the options. As for submitting the data, you can use either template forms or Reactive Forms. The difference is you would use ngModel for the template forms and FormGroups for reactive forms. Then you would submit either the model or the form group to your service. If you want to not use a select, I think you can add a property in the .ts file and set the button text to that property. Then add a click event to the a tag where you update the property based on the clicked item. Hope this helps

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried it with "select" and it works fine but I wanted to know the syntax of the above dropdown if I wanted to use data-binding with that because I'm using Bootstrap 4 and it's kinda easy in terms of styling and stuff.